# Replacing comma with ','

Tags: oracle

Editing my question:-

I am using using replace function of oracle to replace `,` with `','`
but Oracle is throwing an error that two many arguments for function.

```
SELECT value
FROM person
WHERE value IN REPLACE(rakesh,satish, ',' ,'','');
```

rakesh and satish have a primary key in person table which i want to retrieve.

Is there any way to do this using sql.

Comment: What do you mean with "is not working" ? it's returning an error? which version or Oracle are you using? the first statement should be correct.

Comment: Hi Vargan...thanks for the reply.I have just changed my question.I think i was not sure what i was asking at that time.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to use replace this way... `SELECT REPLACE('rakesh,satish', ',' ,''',''')
FROM Dual`? which yields `rakesh','satish`

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply,It is working as expected.Do we have a way to have a quote at the start and end as 'rakesh','satish'

Comment: Yep `SELECT REPLACE('''rakesh,satish''', ',' ,''',''')  FROM Dual`  but I think this is about to become a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Hi xQbert, i used the concat two times and it is also working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use chr(39):

```
SELECT REPLACE('rakesh,satish', ',' ,chr(39)||','||chr(39))
FROM DUAL;
```

Output:

```
rakesh','satish
```

Comment: It is working as expected.Do we have a way to have a quote at the start and end as 'rakesh','satish'

Comment: SELECT chr(39)||REPLACE('rakesh,satish', ',' ,chr(39)||','||chr(39))||chr(39)
FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 1):

Answering the original version of your question:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e10605/1)

If you create a function to split the list into a collection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION splitList(
  str   VARCHAR2,
  delim VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST DETERMINISTIC
AS
  o_list SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  p_prev NUMBER(4,0) := 1;
  p_next NUMBER(4,0);
BEGIN
  o_list := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
  IF ( str IS NULL ) THEN
    NULL;
  ELSIF ( delim IS NULL ) THEN
    o_list.EXTEND( 1 );
    o_list(1) := str;
  ELSE
    p_next := INSTR( str, delim, p_prev, 1 );
    WHILE ( p_next > 0 ) LOOP
      IF ( p_next > p_prev ) THEN
        o_list.EXTEND( 1 );
        o_list( o_list.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( str, p_prev, p_next - p_prev );
      END IF;
      p_prev := p_next + LENGTH( delim );
      p_next := INSTR( str, delim, p_prev, 1 );
    END LOOP;
    IF ( p_prev <= LENGTH( str ) ) THEN
      o_list.EXTEND( 1 );
      o_list( o_list.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( str, p_prev );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN o_list;
END splitList;
/
```

Then you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA ( primary_key, value ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'ab' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'cd' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'e' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'f' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'gh' FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TABLE TableB ( value ) AS
SELECT 'ab,cd,f' FROM DUAL
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT primary_key
FROM   TableA
WHERE  value IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
                  FROM   TABLE(
                           splitList(
                             ( SELECT value
                               FROM TableB
                             )
                           )
                         )
                 )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e10605/1/0)**:

```
| PRIMARY_KEY |
|-------------|
|           1 |
|           2 |
|           4 |
```