# how to add single quote to the end and beginning of value retrieved in select statement

Tags: oracle

I have a select sql which returns a string like joe','rose','chandler
I need to get the result like 'joe','rose','chandler' using sql
I am trying to use || but not successful.

```
SELECT '''||NAME||'''
FROM 
(SELECT REPLACE(joe,rose,chandler, ',' ,''',''') AS NAME
FROM TABLE.
```

joe,rose,chandler is the value retrieved from column of Table.

Now the NAME is being treated as a string rather than a value retrieved from sql.
Can any one please help.

Comment: See comment on your prior post on this topic... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574450/replacing-comma-with#comment49225210_30574450

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like in the answer above described, if you only want to concat an `'` to a string the syntax is
`''''` || string1 || `''''`
however, if you want to add a string like "`'start of sentence`" you can use `'''`
so:

`''' begin of sentence ' || string1 || ' end of sentence '''`

results in:

`' begin of sentence string1 end of sentence'`

Full example could be sth like

```sql
SELECT ''''||col1||''', '''|| col2 ||''', '''|| col3||'''' AS OUTPUT FROM (
SELECT 'Joe' as col1, 'Rose' as col2, 'Chandeler' AS col3 FROM dual);
```

```sql
|          OUTPUT          |
+--------------------------+
|'Joe', 'Rose', 'Chandeler'|
```

Answer (score 2):

Below sql solved my problem.

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('''',NAME),'''')
FROM
(SELECT REPLACE(joe,rose,chandler, ',' ,''',''') AS NAME
FROM TABLE)
```